# Is wp_posts table post delete cause any issues?

Tags: php, wordpress

If I simply delete my unwanted posts from wp_posts and not deleting in rest of the tables(terms, taxonomy and relationships), then is this will cause any 404 error's or something else in my site?

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are deleting posts that have been published, then yes, you will have 404 problems.  You may have other issues, as well, because you are not deleting all of the related data.  Is there a reason you want to do it this way rather than through wp-admin?

Comment: Actually I have to delete only duplicate posts

Comment: Are they true duplicates, with the same URL? Or only with the same content?  Either way, this is somewhat risky.

Comment: same URL.. Now my problem is for a same URL I'm getting all the duplicate and the original together. Like posts are repeating for that URL.

Comment: I would still try to do it via wp-admin, unless you're talking about lots and lots of posts.  I would **strongly** recommend testing whatever you plan to do on a mockup of your site first (like a local LAMP/WAMP stack).  And be sure you have a backup!

Comment: No I cant do it via wp-admin because it is very large number.

Comment: Im not going to change URL. URL will be the same. Only I'm just clearing duplicates.

Comment: I'd still recommend doing it in wp-admin but if you are going to do it at the db level, set everything up properly on a testing server and test it there first.